# MVC 5 Nonfactorsgrid is not working. Something is wrong withing the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, razor-pages

```
@using AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common.Models.Users
@model IEnumerable<UserSearchModel>

@(Html
        .Grid(Model)
        .Build(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
            columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");
            columns.Add(model => model.MaritalStatus).Titled("Marital status");

            columns.Add(model => model.Age).Titled("Age");
            columns.Add(model => model.Birthday).Titled("Birthday").Formatted("{0:d}");
            columns.Add(model => model.IsWorking).Titled("Employed");
        })
        .Empty("No data found")
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        )
```

I am using Nonfactors grid for MVC 5 asp and I have installed it from the NuGet package manager but whenever i am trying to implement the grid in Razor it gives me this error:

**HtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'Grid' and no extension method 'Grid' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I have really tried everything I can, but no luck so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are supposed to import the namespace in your HTML file.

```
@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;
```

Comment: Hi... Even I added this namespace but still it throw error showing "NonFactors couldnot be found"... although i have installed Nonfactors.Grid.mvc5. Any help will be appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't even creating MvcGrid folder inside the Content, Script, and Shared folders. But I can use @using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid; on the view. It doesn't complain. Is there project settings that limits this?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same and the Content/Script/etc path is different from the last version for MVC6 which is showing up on their manual site, so try it find and add the link manualy

```
<link href="~/Content/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.js"></script>
```